# SQLite database is not found after publishing a C# WPF MVVM program

Tags: c#, database, wpf, sqlite, publish

I have made a piece of software that contains a SQLite database (*.db).

In visual studio everything works fine, after I have build the solution it finds its database in the C# source:

```
private String strDataBase = URI=file:Database/database.db";
```

Although the file (database.db) is located in the follwing path:

> ProjectLibrary\bin\Debug\Database\database.db

Inside my solution I have made a Database folder containing the Database.db file (referring to the link above).
I have included the file in the Application Files as Publish status: **Data File** and Download group as **(Required)**

After publishing the Database folder is there containing the database file (which is renamed to Database.db.deploy). Though the application crashes as soon as I want to access the database.

I have tried several options on Stackoverflow and none of them helped.
I have read about SQLite.Interop.dll which is inside my published build. It did not help.
I have tried copying the Database.db file to several folders inside my installation folder. None of them are the right location.

Comment: Where is the application installed?  Program Files?